# Unable to compute pairwise associations over all columns in dataframe?

Tags: r, pairwise

```
work<-expand.grid(paste0('df$',names(df)),paste0('df$',names(df)))
SomersD <- c()
for (j in 1:nrow(work))
  SomersD<-c(SomersD,SomersDelta(work[j,]$Var1,work[j,]$Var2))

 work<-
         Var1         Var2
    1 df$Polymer.1 df$Polymer.1
    2 df$Polymer.2 df$Polymer.1
    3 df$Polymer.3 df$Polymer.1
    4 df$Polymer.4 df$Polymer.1
    5  df$Filler.1 df$Polymer.1
    6  df$Filler.2 df$Polymer.1
...
```

But now when I try to loop over every single row in my work matrix and calculate the SomersDelta between the corresponding entires, I just get NaNs.

I want to compute `SomersDelta(df$Polymer.1, df$Filler.1)` if my row has those two corresponding entries, for example. For some reason, this isn't working and I have no idea why.

Help?

====

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 14
  Polymer.1 Polymer.2 Polymer.3 Polymer.4 Filler.1 Filler.2 Filler.3 Oil.1 Oil.2 Co.Agent.1 Co.Agent.2 Tensile.Strength Elongation
      <int>     <int>     <int>     <int>    <int>    <int>    <int> <int> <int>      <dbl>      <dbl>            <dbl>      <dbl>
1       100         0         0         0       50        0        0    30     0        2.4        0               8.38       188.
2       100         0         0         0       50        0        0     0    30        2.4        0               8.40       180.
3       100         0         0         0       60        0        0     0    36        1.7        1               8.40       130.
4       100         0         0         0       40        0        0    24     0        2.1        0.4             9.05       192.
5         0         0       100         0        0       50        0     0    30        0.6        2.3             9.44       162.
6         0         0         0       100       50        0        0    30     0        1.3        1.7             8.87       227.
```

Comment: Could you also include `df` or a sample of `df` in your question using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Just FYI, `dput` allows us to enter your data into R without having to reconstruct it via pasting (far better for asking questions on SO than `head(df)`)